# login in facebook with python

Tags: python, facebook, cookies, authentication, keep-alive

I can login to facebook with this code. After login I can access a page that requires you to be logged in.

```
def SignIn(self):
    url = 'https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1'
    data = "locale=en_US&non_com_login=&email="+str(self.Username)+"&pass="+str(self.Password)+"&lsd=20TOl"
    self.cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()

    try:
        self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cookie))
    except:
        sys.stderr.write("Unexpected error!".format(src))

    try:
         self.opener.open('https://www.facebook.com')
    except:
         sys.stderr.write("Unexpected error!1")

    try:
         self.opener.open(url, data)
    except:
        sys.stderr.write("Unexpected error!2")

    self.IsSignIned=True  
    return self.opener
```

But this code doesn't work

```
import requests


headers = {'Host':'www.facebook.com',
'Origin':'http://www.facebook.com',
'Referer':'http://www.facebook.com/',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11'}


s = requests.session(headers=headers)
login_data = {
    'locale':'en_US',
    'non_com_login':'',
    'email':'mymail@mail.com',
    'pass':'mypassword',
    'lsd':'20TOl'
    }

r=s.post('https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1',data=login_data,verify=False)
print r.content
print r.status_code
```

It returns

> Facebook Login
>
> Cookies Required
>
> Cookies are not enabled on your browser. Please adjust this in your
>   security preferences before continuing.

I must use requests library because I need  Gzip and keep-alive

What is the problem?
Is there any other library that can handle all of this? (Gzip ,Keep-alive cookie ,..)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you're saying, but perhaps you just need to enable cookies in your browser?

Comment: i use  python not any browser

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need to do all the stuff yourself? Did you try facepy (https://github.com/jgorset/facepy)?

That library uses the "requests" as well but I'm sure they solved that (assuming you want to login because you need an access token to do OpenGraph stuff).

Answer (score 0):

self.cookie =,cookielib.CookieJar() 
you didnt activate python cookie in the second code.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and thought you want to get information after login. Below is my code to show the HTML content, does it solve your problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

username = 'yourusername'

password = 'yourpassword'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})

opener.open('https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1', login_data)

resp = opener.open('http://www.facebook.com/')

print resp.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) to auto login wechat in China. The code is here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # open firefox browser
driver.get('https://mp.weixin.qq.com/') # go to url 

wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded)

wechat_account = driver.find_element_by_id("account") # here you should find the facebook login account id in webpage sourcecode and change the string "account"
wechat_account.send_keys("user@email.com")      # input your email address or your wechat account

your_password = driver.find_element_by_id("pwd")
your_password.send_keys("balabalabala")         # your password instead of balabalabala
your_password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

print "Mission Completed! Write your new article.-->"
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver  ##Imports the selenium web driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()    ##Create a Firefox Webdriver
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")  ##Tells the driver to go to     facebook.com
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#email").send_keys("insert username here")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#pass").send_keys("insert password  here")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#u_0_q").click()
```

For a more in depth guide i suggest you give [this post](http://strawbot.com/python-selenium-facebook-login-tutorial/) a look